# Variable environment of execution context JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In the [**sec. 10.3**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) describes the components of execution context as the follwoing:

> The LexicalEnvironment and VariableEnvironment components of an
>   execution context are always Lexical Environments. When an execution
>   context is created its LexicalEnvironment and VariableEnvironment
>   components initially have the same value. The value of the
>   VariableEnvironment component never changes while the value of the
>   LexicalEnvironment component may change during execution of code
>   within an execution context.

Ok, let we have code snippet:

```
{
    alert(o.prop);
    var o={prop: 'prop'};
}
```

#### My understanding of this code snippet:

When control is transferred to this code snippet a corresponding execution context will be created and pushed to stack. This context is become a running execution context (called `cont`). During the `cont` is creating the `VariableEnvironment` of `cont` is creating. After the `cont`'s creation this code starting to execute.

But as said in [**sec.10.3**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3)

> The value of the VariableEnvironment component never changes

Thus we can assume that the `VariableEnvironment` never changed after creation of `cont`. I.e. environment record of `cont`'s `VariableEnvironment` contains all binding created by `VariableStatement` and `FunctionDeclarartion` initially. Hence we can apply to object by reference `o`. But I have `TypeError: o is undefined`.

Question:
Why `TypeError`, described above is caused? I'm expected that `prop` will be displayed with alert message because `the value of the VariableEnvironment component never changes` hence environment record of the `VariableEnvironment` never changes, hence all bindings of this record is immutable.

Might I dont understand mean of `value of EnvironmentRecord` correctly?

Comment: I'm afraid this question doesn't make a lot of sense, not least because you mention `TypeError: a is undefined` but there's no `a` anywhere in the code you quote...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your code is just definining a *block*, and JavaScript doesn't have block scope; environment records are associated with global scope and functions, not blocks.

So let's assume that's actually a function so it creates a new scope and environment record:

```
function foo()
{
    alert(o.prop);
    var o={prop: 'prop'};
}
```

That's treated exactly as though it were this:

```
function foo()
{
    var o;
    o = undefined;
    alert(o.prop);
    o={prop: 'prop'};
}
```

Which should clarify things a bit. :-) You're trying to dereference `o` as though it referred to an object, but it doesn't (yet); its value is `undefined`.

This is because all `var` declarations are processed upon entry to the execution context, and all variables are initialized to `undefined`, before any step-by-step work is done. Any *initializer* associated with a `var` (e.g., `var o = ...`) is really an assignment, and happens later when that code is reached in the step-by-step execution of the code.

More *(on my blog)*:

- [Poor misunderstood `var`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! But what does mean _The value of the VariableEnvironment component never changes_? Does it mean that we can't add a new binding to `VariableEnvironment`'s environment record?

Comment: @St.Antario: It has to do with the `with` statement; it's discussed in [§12.10](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.10). The `with` statement creates a new *LexicalEnvironment* that is augmented with the properties on the object that results from the expression you give `with`, then executes the statement (which is almost always going to be a *Block* statement), then restores the old lexical environment. This has no effect on the *VariableEnvironment*. That's why *VariableEnvironment* doesn't change but *LexicalEnvironment* may.